# How to manage null value for android application while JSON parsing via GSON lib in kotlin

Tags: android, json, api, parsing, null

I am working on android application and want to manage null value that is comes from API.
I did not found the best solution.

I also try these methods

**1. While generating getter in model class i give a conditional statement in getter like**

```
if(value == null){
value = ""
}
```

but this is not a right way because of i have to write this code for each and every getter in whole application.

**2. replace the string from 'null' to "" before JSON parsing.**

this is replace all type of value (int/float etc) in to blank string that is invalid.

Comment: Do you want to replace null value with "" as you did above? Or you just want to create a model class that is flexible of handling null value and data as well?

Comment: @Black4Guy I don't want to assign null value in my model class variables

Comment: According to your 2 point. yes, you cannot add the double quote "" to int and float, you can assign int as 0 and float as 0f default value in that case.

Comment: If you don't want to assign null value in your model then at some point you have to check for null value like you did in the model or during JSON to Model deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonDeserializer` to create your `Gson`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can create model class like this**

```
class ExampleModel {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
 val id: Int? = null
@SerializedName("category")
@Expose
 val category: String? = null
```

}

This class will be able to handle null value and data as well.